# Debian 11 is zoomed by default

Tags: debian, zoom

I installed Debian os 11 which I got zoomed desktop by default. Have big icons and a taskbar. how can I zoom out? keyboard shortcut not working out. I tried both cinnabar and gnome desktop environment.

Comment: dpi settings of the screen too high?

Comment: Or a wrong display driver?

Comment: Dots Per Inch (DPI) measures the number of dots or pixels per horizontal or vertical inch on a monitor. how can it related to my problem? I have linux mint it works fine? why only debian seem to very zoomed desktop?

Comment: The desktop environment might be looking at the display's DPI value and resolution to figure out how many pixels high each desktop element should be to achieve the "standard" size on various display sizes and resolutions. If a display reports an untrue DPI value, you might get a "zoomed" desktop with either too-large or too-small text and graphic elements. Displays can also report their physical size in their EDID information: if the physical size + resolution and the reported DPI don't agree, the system must choose which data to believe. Your system may have guessed the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu.
Fixed it by turning off the zoom from settings>accessibility menu.